# Unexpected Stack Layout behavior in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout with a Frame, ScrollView & Button as it's child controls.
When the ScrollView content is beyond a certain Height, the ScrollView seems to push the Frame above it, squashing it. I would expect that the ScrollView as a container not push upwards the view above it, but contain its content within it.

Frame - red circle, ScrollView - Blue, ScrollView's content - light blue, Button - green

> EXPECTED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Class">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Vertical">

             <Frame
                 Padding="0"
                 HeightRequest="60"
                 WidthRequest="60"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 CornerRadius="30"
                 BackgroundColor="Red"/>

             <ScrollView
                 Background="Blue"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                 <StackLayout
                     Margin="20,5,20,0"
                     BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                     HeightRequest="150"/>
             </ScrollView>
        

             <Button
                 VerticalOptions="End"
                 Text="Next"
                 BackgroundColor="Green"/>
             </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

> Ouputs (Which is what i expect):

[image]

Then if i change the ScrollView's StackLayout content's height to 950, it then squashes the content above and it looks as below:

[image]

Why is the ScrollView pushing upwards, even when the Frame has an assigned `HeightRequest`. How can i resolve this?

Comment: I hypothesize it is because `Frame` is designed to wrap another view. It has no children forcing a height, so its HeightRequest is merely a suggestion.  1) Try wrapping it around a BoxView whose HeightRequest is 60. `<Frame ...><BoxView HeightRequest="60"/></Frame>`. OR 2) Make outermost layout `Grid` instead of `StackLayout`. Easier to enforce the desired layout using `row heights` "Auto", "60", "*", "Auto". Also add `Grid.Row="0"`, `Grid.Row="1"` etc on children of grid.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the ScrollView pushing upwards, even when the Frame has an assigned HeightRequest.

From [ScrollView as a child layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scrollview-as-a-child-layout), a ScrollView will often be the child of a StackLayout. A ScrollView requires a specific height to compute the difference between the height of its content and its own height, with the difference being the amount that the ScrollView can scroll its content.

So you can assign specific height  to Scrollview.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            CornerRadius="30"
            HeightRequest="60"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="60" />

        <ScrollView
            Background="Blue"
            HeightRequest="150"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout
                Margin="20,5,20,0"
                BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                HeightRequest="950" />
        </ScrollView>
        <Button
            BackgroundColor="Green"
            Text="Next"
            VerticalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Another way is to use [Gird](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) to assign specific height for Scrollview.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            CornerRadius="30"
            HeightRequest="60"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="60" />

        <ScrollView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="Blue"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout
                Margin="20,5,20,0"
                BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                HeightRequest="950" />
        </ScrollView>


        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            BackgroundColor="Green"
            Text="Next"
            VerticalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
```